# Getting a worker to change queues for delayed_jobs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, queue, delayed-job

Ok.. I have an issue with worker management. 

I have 30/n clients.. 

   Each with a pile of things/jobs to get done. 

   Each with their own "schema" in postgresqu.

   Non should ever block another..

So my thinking was to have a queue for each.. 
But then I have the problem how do I handle queues.. A worker for say 10 queues would have the same problem.. He'd not get to client 2 if he was working on client 1's stuff.

A worker for each queue.. Okay.. that's expensive.. We could create a worker per client and leave it running at all times (we got piles of dough, just like everyone else.)

So workers on the fly seems the best option.

But then we've got the build up and tear down issue, and scheduling is also a right pain.

A suggestion was put to have a single worker doing nothing but starting and stopping workers. 
The issue I have is that I don't want to have the build up and tear down..

So here's my thinking.. I might have a worker on Q_A who's only got one job left for client A.. **Could I switch his que.. make him work on Q_B stuff?**

I was (for a second) thinking of switching the queue that a job was assigned to, to the existing workers queue, but then new stuff for Q_A would be behind that..

Any ideas? Alternatives to switching a workers Q would be much appreciated.

Comment: What's so wrong with the setup-and-teardown costs? How much does it cost to start a worker and stop a worker?

Comment: it's a whole linux process, that has to load your rails environment.. so 30 seconds.. * 30 clients * 100 jobs a day..

Comment: also 30 clients is just a starting point.. who knows where it will go.

Comment: The last time I loaded the whole rails environment on my system, it started in roughly .5 seconds with a hot cache and 2 seconds with a cold cache. If the cache is cold, hooray, you don't use it much, and if it is hot, hooray, it loads relatively quickly.

Comment: wow.. What I've read has cautioned me against spawning workers. The build-up and tear down was the issue. If it's not.. well then I might as well.

Comment: I wouldn't spawn workers _blindly_ -- maybe let one worker handle tasks until there are five or more queued up -- but you might as well code for what is most clean first and then optimize it further if it doesn't scale well.

Comment: Ok.. so client A has task that takes an hour(updating all his products because he changed shipping fee's), client_b wants to have the price of one product adjusted.  2 Jobs = 1 worker.. Thats with two clients.:)  not so good on the scaling eh?  :)